# $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2/2}dx= 1$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

$X \sim N(0, 1)$

$$E(|X|) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|e^{-x^2/2}dx= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

I don't understand how the last equality was arrived at. Why is it seemingly obvious that $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2/2}dx= 1$?

Is this some common identity?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2/2} = -x e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: The harder case is $\int e^{⁻x^2} dx$, which can be solved with a nice trick from Poisson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps that help make it obvious,
\[
\int_0^\infty xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx = \lim_{\beta \to \infty}\int_0^\beta xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx 
\]
Let $u=\frac{-x^2}{2}$ then,
\[ \frac{d}{dx}u = -x \Rightarrow du = -x\ dx \Rightarrow-du=x\ dx \]
So now after adjusting the limits, we have
\[ 
\lim_{\beta \to -\infty}-\int_0^\beta e^{u}\ du = \lim_{\beta \to -\infty}\int_\beta^0 e^{u}\ du = \lim_{\beta \to -\infty} e^u\Bigg|^0_\beta = \lim_{\beta \to -\infty}\left(e^0 - e^\beta\right) = 1 - 0 = 1
\]
I hope this helps you understand the equation.

Comment: There are many very minor edits to this post. It is best to collect changes into one larger edit. It is not permitted to make edits simply to keep a question on the front page. If a question is not getting enough attention, [improve the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) with significant edits or [start a bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @robjohn, I mostly edit my posts via the mobile app. A "save draft" feature would be nice but I digress.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it obvious that

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}=-e^{-x^2/2}\Bigg|_0^\infty=1\qquad?$$

Comment: The denominator in the exponent is missing.

Comment: Although this is obvious to you, me and perhaps many other people. Its obviously not obvious to the person asking the question. By the way, your improper integral is obviously missing the dx.

Comment: It is obvious to me now after seeing it multiple times over the last few weeks. But it was not obvious back when I asked this question. Things only become obvious with experience!

Answer (score 3):

I would substitute $u(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2$  $\Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=-x\Rightarrow -du=x \ dx$

$ -\int_0^{-\infty}   e^{u} \ du $

The upper limit  has been adjusted. The limits can be switched:

$ \int_{-\infty} ^0  e^{u} \ du $

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2} \Big( x\,dx\Big) = \int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,du.
$$